# Creating a new String using a byte array is giving a strange result

Tags: java, file-io, randomaccessfile

I am reading a file using the `readFully` method of `RandomAccessFile` class, but the results are not what I exactly expected.

This is the simple function which reads the file and returns a `new String` using the byte array where all the bytes are stored:

```
public String read(int start)
{
    setFilePointer(start);//Sets the file pointer

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) (_file.length() - start)];

    try
    {
        _randomStream.readFully(bytes);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(bytes);
}
```

In the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    String filePath = "C:/users/userZ/Desktop/myFile.txt";
    RandomFileManager rfmanager = new RandomFileManager(filePath, FileOpeningMode.READ_WRITE);

    String content = rfmanager.read(10);

    System.out.println("\n"+content);

    rfmanager.closeFile();
}
```

This function is called in the constructor of the `RandomFileManager`. It creates the file, if it doesn't exist already.

```
private void setRandomFile(String filePath, String mode)
{
    try
    {
        _file = new File(filePath);

        if(!_file.exists())
        {

            _file.createNewFile();// Throws IOException
            System.out.printf("New file created.");
        }
        else System.out.printf("A file already exists with that name.");

        _randomStream = new RandomAccessFile(_file, mode);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I write to the file using this write method:

```
public void write(String text)
{
    //You can also write
    if(_mode == FileOpeningMode.READ_WRITE)
    {
        try
        {
            _randomStream.writeChars(text);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else System.out.printf("%s", "Warning!");
}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used the writeChars method.

This write all characters as UTF-16 which is unlikely to be the default encoding.  If you use UTF-16BE character encoding, this will decode the characters.  UTF_16 uses two bytes, per character.

If you only need characters between `(char) 0` and `(char) 255` I suggest using ISO-8859-1 encoding as it will be half the size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not specifying a Charset and so the "platform default" is being used.  This is almost always a bad idea.  Instead, use [this constructor: String(byte[], Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))  and be explicit about the encoding the file was written with.  Given the output you are showing, it appears to be a two-byte encoding, likely UTF-16BE.

Short answer: bytes are not characters